# Expel, Dismiss and Terminate. What are the differences?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

I know that Expel, Dismiss and Terminate literally mean:

> force someone to leave an organization or an school.

But I wonder if there are any slight differences in the meaning or the way we should use them or not?

Thanks

Comment: ***Terminate*** is business-speak jargon for ***to fire, to sack***, and ***dismiss*** is military / schoolteacher jargon for ***allow to go** [after formally-enforced attendance].* And you can ***expel*** mucus by sneezing violently, but ***dismiss*** and ***terminate*** don't work at all there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with regard to your given definition, there are differences

"Expel" is normally used for educational and similar institutions:

> The students were **expelled** from the school for threatening one of the teachers.

You can also use "expel" for businesses and other professional organizations, but this usually suggests some kind of power struggle between equals:

> The original partners were **expelled** from the company during a hostile takeover by a rival.

You can also "expel" ordinary people

> The party-crashers were forcibly **expelled** after the host found no one knew who they were, but they managed to take a few bottles with them as they went.

---

"Dismiss" can be used for any official position in a business or professional organization.

> The shareholders voted to **dismiss** the current board of directors after the scandal and disastrous drop in sales.

With students (and military, police, security, and personnel of other related jobs that have some measure of military-style discipline), "dismiss" means to "let out of class or other activity" and not "kick out".

> Because of the power outage, the students were **dismissed** early and allowed to go home.
>
> The soldiers were required to stand at attention on the parade ground for three hours until the sergeant finally **dismissed** them for chow.

---

"Terminate" almost exclusively refers to an employer/employee or other working relationship.  Because of its association with "assassination" (e.g. "The Terminator") it's somewhat better to say their *employment* or *working relationship* or *contract* was terminated rather than the *people* were terminated.

> The employees were found drinking on the job and immediately had their employment **terminated**.

"Terminate" normally suggests a superior/inferior power relationship, as only someone higher in the organization can "terminate" someone lower.  Generally it's used for regular employees and not executives.  Executives are more frequently "asked to resign" or "dismissed", to imply a smooth transition of power, but it can be used to suggest an extreme situation:

> The CFO was found to have been embezzling company funds and **was terminated** on the spot.